# Loop and assign non-unique GUID to sets of values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, guid

I'm sure this in easy one, but I can't go past conceptualization to syntax: I have a table of features where one named feature may populate several rows e.g:

```
[NAME], [GUID]
Fred, NULL
Fred, NULL
Fred, NULL
Tom, Null
Mary, Null
Mary, Null
Mary, Null
Mary, Null
```

What I'd like to do is assign ONE GUID per name:

```
Fred, {3b26af27-9d42-481c-a8c8-be1819dccda5}
Fred, {3b26af27-9d42-481c-a8c8-be1819dccda5}
Fred, {3b26af27-9d42-481c-a8c8-be1819dccda5}
Tom, {ee64b706-def0-4e5c-a5fd-0c219962042e}
Mary, {fd158f90-9705-4a18-b82c-baca29441401}
Mary, {fd158f90-9705-4a18-b82c-baca29441401}
Mary, {fd158f90-9705-4a18-b82c-baca29441401}
Mary, {fd158f90-9705-4a18-b82c-baca29441401}
```

Comment: What does the guid represent?

Comment: A unique identifier assigned to a name for relation with other tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
(
    Name    varchar(30),
    GUID    uniqueidentifier
)

INSERT @tmp
    SELECT  x.Name, NEWID()
    FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM MyTable) x

UPDATE MyTable
    SET GUID = tmp.GUID
    FROM MyTable t
    INNER JOIN @tmp tmp ON t.Name = tmp.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `NEWID()` doesn't materialize until the very end of a query, you will need to materialize it  temporarily. Here I use a table variable to store a single new GUID per name (by grouping on `Name`) before using that table to update the final destination:

```
DECLARE @MaterializedGuids TABLE (
    Name varchar(20),
    NewGuid uniqueidentifier
)

INSERT INTO @MaterializedGuids (Name, NewGuid)
SELECT Name, NEWID() FROM YourTable GROUP BY Name
```

Now you can use this in-memory table to update your permanent table:

```
UPDATE y
SET y.[Guid] = x.[NewGuid]
FROM YourTable y
JOIN @MaterializedGuids x ON x.Name = y.Name
```

Then check out the results:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to the mysterious poster who deleted his answer minutes after he posted it, it sort of worked:

```
UPDATE y
SET y.[FEATUREID] = x.[NewGUID]
FROM TRANS_TRAILS_LN y
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT TRAILNAME, NEWID() AS NewGuid FROM TRANS_TRAILS_LN GROUP BY TRAILNAME
) x ON x.TRAILNAME = y.TRAILNAME
```

Comment: That was me after I realized it didn't work. I have updated my answer and undeleted it.